# self.env dont insert or insert duplicated

Tags: python, odoo

I have a list that can have duplicate items, when i try to insert with IndexError I get a duplicate item exception!

But if I use Exception instead of IndexErro the self.env inserts duplicate

Just wanted to insert, if there is a duplicate item I give a pass and do not enter

```
                    try:
                        self.env['hr.attendance'].create({
                            'create_uid':'99',
                            'check_in': str(checkin),
                            'employee_id':int(item.employeeId), 
                            'worked_hours':str(item.workedHours),
                            'create_date': str(createDate),
                            'write_date': str(writeDate),
                            'check_out': str(checkOut),
                            'write_uid':'99',       
                            'banco_horas': str((item.workedHours - 4)),           
                            'sheet_id':1})    

                        self.env.cr.commit()
                    except IndexError:
                        pass
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you are saying, the exception is raised when you use exception handler (IndexError) and when you use Exception the exception is not raised!! is you mean this you are wrong your code is raising an exception but it's not indexError and when you use Exception you are handling a lot of exception type. didn't understand what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

you just remove this line

```
self.env.cr.commit()
```

If you are already created the record then you dont need to commit again.